# MySQL COUNT performance while grouping

Tags: mysql, performance, count, group-by, innodb

Does `COUNT(*)` have any significant impact for MySQL performance if query already has `GROUP BY` statement.

Table engine is InnoDB.

`EXPLAIN SELECT <...>` provides same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output in `explain` is the same then there is no difference. And counting rows doesn't have a **significant** impact on performance anyway.

Comment: Counting rows has impact on InnoDB tables, because rows count is not stored in table metadata like in MyISAM tables.

Comment: Incrementing a variable for every row is probably not measurable in performace

Comment: There is difference if server needs load all table data to calculate rows instead of reading single value. But I've got your point and thanks for answer.